# Replace NA value with next or previous non-NA value conditional on other column

Tags: r, na, zoo

Below is an example data set similar to what I'm working with.

```
df<-data.frame(Loc=c(rev(seq(-4,5,1)),seq(-4,5,1)),
           Reg=c("A",rep(NA,8),"B",rep(NA,9),"C"))
```

In this example we have a string of values ranging from + to - values or vice versa (Loc). What I am trying to do accomplish is to fill these NA values, where B is always a associated with negative values of Loc, however, positive values can either take on values A if NA's are between A and B or C if NA's are between B and C.

The desired output should look like the following

```
df2<-data.frame(Loc=c(rev(seq(-4,5,1)),seq(-4,5,1)),
           Reg=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",8),rep("C",6)))
```

I have looked into the na.locf from the zoo package but I'm not sure how to order which direction the funcion looks for the non-NA value to get the desired output.

```
df$Reg2<-ifelse(df$Loc<=0,df$Reg2<-"B",na.locf(df$Reg,fromLast = F))
```

The above code is only returning the right response for some of the rows depending on the direction (i.e. fromLast = T or F)

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ave` splitting by a grouping variable generated from `rleid` of the sign.  Then omit the NAs leaving the single non-NA in each group which `ave` will copy for all values in that group.

```
library(data.table)

transform(df, Reg = ave(Reg, rleid(Loc >= 0), FUN = na.omit))
```

giving:

```
   Loc Reg
1    5   A
2    4   A
3    3   A
4    2   A
5    1   A
6    0   A
7   -1   B
8   -2   B
9   -3   B
10  -4   B
11  -4   B
12  -3   B
13  -2   B
14  -1   B
15   0   C
16   1   C
17   2   C
18   3   C
19   4   C
20   5   C
```

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck This is great. Not familiar with rleid or the ave functions but the result works both here and on actual data. Much appreciated. Just wish I asked this question 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution which reproduces OP's expected answer:

```
library(data.table)
result <- as.data.table(df)[, Reg := first(Reg[!is.na(Reg)]), by = rleid(Loc >= 0)][]
result
```

> ```
>     Loc Reg
>  1:   5   A
>  2:   4   A
>  3:   3   A
>  4:   2   A
>  5:   1   A
>  6:   0   A
>  7:  -1   B
>  8:  -2   B
>  9:  -3   B
> 10:  -4   B
> 11:  -4   B
> 12:  -3   B
> 13:  -2   B
> 14:  -1   B
> 15:   0   C
> 16:   1   C
> 17:   2   C
> 18:   3   C
> 19:   4   C
> 20:   5   C
> ```

```
identical(as.data.frame(result), df2)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

Note that this approach is similar to [G. Grothendiek's base R solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49054003/3817004) in that it uses `rleid(Loc >= 0)` to group the data but it does not call `transform()` and `ave()` but updates `Reg` by reference, i.e., without copying the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution with dplyr:

```
df<-data.frame(Loc=c(rev(seq(-4,5,1)),seq(-4,5,1)),
           Reg=c("A",rep(NA,8),"B",rep(NA,9),"C")) 
c <- match("C",df$Reg)
a <- match("A",df$Reg)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(newReg=case_when(Loc < 0 ~ "B",
                      Loc >= 0 & abs(row_number()-c)<abs(row_number()-a)~ "C",
                      TRUE ~ "A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is hideous and I am doubtful this is reproducible for more use cases... this is probably better suited for some type of `dplyr::case_when` function, but I just couldn't think it through at this point.

```
lapply(2:nrow(df), function(i){
    this_row <- df[i, ]
    last_row <- i - 1 
    if(is.na(this_row[['Reg']])){
        if(this_row[['Loc']] < 0){
            df[i, 'Reg'] <<- "B"
        }else if(df[i - 1, 'Reg'] == "A"){
            df[i, 'Reg'] <<- "A"
        }else {
            df[i, "Reg"] <<- "C"
        }
    }
})



> df
   Loc Reg
1    5   A
2    4   A
3    3   A
4    2   A
5    1   A
6    0   A
7   -1   B
8   -2   B
9   -3   B
10  -4   B
11  -4   B
12  -3   B
13  -2   B
14  -1   B
15   0   C
16   1   C
17   2   C
18   3   C
19   4   C
20   5   C
```